R: Conditional suppression of values across multiple columns
I have a huge data. I like to suppress data across multiple columns by replacing any value less than 6 in each column with -1 such that if in a column, there is only one suppressed value, I want to also suppress the next higher value even though higher than 6.
My Dummy data is:
df = structure(list(x = c(1, 25, 9, 50), y = c(1, 35, 8, 6), z = c(4,50, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Expected output is:
   x  y  z
1 -1 -1 -1
2 25 35 50
3 -1  8 -1
4 50 -1 -1

I love map() and thus, my idea of iterating the conditional data suppression over columns did not work out.
column_names1 <- colnames(df)

df |> 
     map(\ (x)
         column_names1 <- colnames(df)
         var <- ensym(y)
         {if((x |> 
              select({{var}}) |> 
              filter({{var}} == -1) |> 
              nrow())==1){
              x |> 
                   mutate(val2 = dense_rank({{var}})) |>
                   mutate(val = ifelse(val2 == 2, -1, val)) |> 
                   select(-val2)
         }else{
              x
         }}
         
     ) |> 
     list_cbind()

Any help will be appreciated.

The data suppression is done column-wise, such that if in a column, there is only one  suppressed value, the next higher value within that same column is also suppressed or recoded. That is why 6 in column y row 4 is recoded despite being above the threshold.

What should happen if there are no values less than 6?

If there are no values less than 6, the values remains the same. No suppression.

You can try:
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(
    everything(),
    \(x) if (sum(x < 6) <= 1)
      replace(x, x %in% sort(unique(x), partial = 2)[1:2], -1)
    else
      replace(x, x < 6, -1)
  ))

   x  y  z
1 -1 -1 -1
2 25 35 50
3 -1  8 -1
4 50 -1 -1


Thanks Iroha. What I love in your approach is the use of dplyr. However, this algorithm still replaces or suppress values that are less than 6. What caused that is the 'if(sum(x < 6) <= 1)which should beif(sum(x < 6) == 1)`. Kudos Iroha.

vapply returns a matrix here. Re-assign and replace additional values (due to duplicates) with df[df < 6] = -1:
df = vapply(df, \(j) { j[order(j)[1:2]] = -1; j }, vector('double', 4)) 
df[df < 6] = -1

> df
     x  y  z
[1,] -1 -1 -1
[2,] 25 35 50
[3,] -1  8 -1
[4,] 50 -1 -1


Get acclimated to R, its rough at first, but its worthwhile learn. I broke what you want in three. First initialization:
df <- data.frame(list(x = c(1, 25, 9, 50), y = c(1, 35, 8, 6), z = c(4,50, 1, 1)))

data.frame is the proper way to create a dataframe. Column names are created with the 'x=' before the name of the column. I think you can name the columns -4 but I don't get it, I didn't work on that, that's offtopic.
df2 <- data.frame(map(df, function(x) {
  ifelse(x<6, x, -1)
}))

First step, put everything under 6 as -1. Everything is a vector in R, so you can just use ifelse to allocate all the values in a single step. You need to collate results with data.frame, to get the list to be cast as a data.frame
 df3 <- data.frame(map(df2, function(x) {
   if(length(x[x==-1])==1) { ifelse(x == min(x[x!=-1]), -1, x) }
}))

Second step, if the number of value == -1 is 1, you change the minimal value ­> -1 to -1. Its the same thing as last time really, just with a condition and trick to get the minus one removed from vector x. min also takes a vector, so to get the minimum without the -1, you just change the vector.
Hope that helps.

Here's a base R approach:
as.data.frame(
  apply(
    df, 
    2, 
    function(x) {
      # Change values < 6 to -1
      x[x < 6] <- -1
      # if only one -1 in column, change next value to -1
      if(sum(x == -1) == 1) {
        x[min(which(x==min(x[x != -1])))] <- -1
      }
      return(x)
    }
  )
)


you can also use a lesser known function called rapply() just fyi `rapply(df,     function(x) {
Change values < 6 to -1
x[x < 6] <- -1
if only one -1 in column, change next value to -1
if(sum(x == -1) == 1) {
x[min(which(x==min(x[x != -1])))] <- -1
}
return(x)
}, how = "replace" )`
